# Should you use edits to change the conclusion of an answer, or should you post a new answer in that case?

Tags: discussion, edits

In one situation on chem SE, I was looking at someone else's answer that I thought used the wrong formula, and I was asking about submitting an edit to change the formula and change the answer (I don't have enough reputation to edit directly; I can only suggest edits).  I was told that in such cases, where you believe the answer is wrong, you shouldn't submit an edit to change the conclusion of the answer, you should submit a new answer.

Is that the general SE consensus?  Don't use edits to fix a wrong answer, but submit a new answer instead?

The risk of submitting a new answer (assuming for the sake of argument that I'm right and the existing answer is incorrect) is that there's still the chance the wrong answer will be upvoted and accepted and mine will get buried.  On the other hand, if I try to fix the existing answer with an edit, this brings it to the answerer's attention and increases the chance of the answer being fixed.

Comment: Is it *your* answer?

Comment: @Catija no the incorrect answer that I'm talking about editing, is someone else's answer.  (I have updated the question to clarify that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a comment brings it to everyone's attention without adding the unwanted disclaimer to the answer that you edited it to fix it because you thought it was incorrect, or making people search the edit history to see why it was edited.

IF the person disagreed with you they can reject the answer costing you a 'reject'. Writing your own supposedly correct answer will earn you more than the 2 Rep you might earn from editing.

It's up to the voters to vote correctly, not your job to worry about it.

You can complain that the answer is incorrect in the comments or their Meta, or try a flag.

Comment: I see the nitpickers bloodshed coming up.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Chris has ~30x my flair and an answer that is similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you believe an answer is wrong you should down-vote (assuming you have 125+ reputation on the site) and, if you believe you have the correct answer, post your own.

If you are correct then your answer should rise to the top as it gains more votes than the wrong answer. The only drawback with this approach is if the existing answer already has a significant positive score that'll be hard to overcome.

If you don't have enough reputation to edit you could suggest an edit, but that runs the risk of being rejected - either by the OP or the reviewers - as it could be seen as changing the meaning of the answer too radically.

Edits fixing the grammar and spelling are fine.