# "How to Format/Tag" uses "►", creating less-accessible "lists"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accessibility, sidebar, list

The "How to Format/Tag" boxes that pop up on the right sidebar when on a question edit page use less-accessible "lists" with the "►" character. For example, there's this in "How To Tag":

> ► complete the sentence: *my question is about...*
> ► use tags that describe things or concepts that are *essential*, not incidental to your question
> ► favor using [existing popular tags](/tags)

The page's markup claims that this is just regular text, not a list, using `<p>` tags:

[image: browser console showing the relevant markup to use "" tags]

Thus, when a screen reader encounters this, it will just read off the name of the Unicode symbol, followed by the text, as if it was a regular paragraph. This is instead of treating it as a list, for example by announcing a "list of 6 items" and then each item's position as "3 of 6" or similar. It also breaks anything else that relies on list behavior. If a user has a keyboard shortcut to jump back to the start of the list they're currently reading, that won't function because the page's markup says there isn't a list.

Curiously, the "How to Edit" box doesn't have this problem. It's properly marked up with `<li>` elements inside a `<ul>`; the only annoyance to a screen reader user would be that the Unicode symbol is read off when looking at the list element.

Please use proper list formatting for the "How to Format/Tag" lists as well. If it's important to maintain the ► character for style reasons, then just follow the model of "How to Edit".

Comment: This list style is also used on the "Moderator Private Message" page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXb6F.png

Comment: When [the "How to Edit" guidance for suggested edits was updated in December 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372647/335251), this issue was incidentally fixed for the "How to Edit" and "How to Format" sidebars shown on the suggested edit page; both sidebars now use actual bullet points and the appropriate HTML for lists. However, I didn't notice at the time that the "How to Tag" guidance had the same problem – and, as @Smitop notes, the guidance on mod-message pages (`/users/message/<messageID>`) has the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been finished. The old ugly arrows are now gone on both the the tag formatting and mod private message info boxes.

> plain old bullet points
> now used more consistently
> good riddance, `dingus`!

Comment: I realize I didn't point it out in the original post, but I just realized the guidance for [editing tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/603) uses this format - mind fixing that too? :)

Comment: No, @bobble. No you're taking it a bit too far.

Comment: @YaakovEllis: What if I ask really nicely? :P