# The "What are Tag Wikis?" editing help uses "►", creating less-accessible "lists"

Tags: feature-request, status-review, tag-wiki, accessibility, sidebar

Related: ["How to Format/Tag" uses "►", creating less-accessible "lists"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370013/how-to-format-tag-uses-creating-less-accessible-lists)

After the previous feature request was posted and implemented, I realized that there was another location with the same accessibility issue: the "What are Tag Wikis?" blurb which appears when [editing tag wikis/excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/603). I [pointed this out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370013/how-to-format-tag-uses-creating-less-accessible-lists#comment1255147_376511) but think that it may have gotten lost in the sea of things-to-do. So, I'm promoting this from a follow-on comment to a proper post in its own right.

I go more in to depth in the other request, but the basic problem is this: the list items in the sidebar *look* like list items, visually, but they are semantically `<p>` elements. This means the browser reads them as paragraphs instead of treating them specially as list items. That affects users who navigate using screen readers most especially.

Please change "What are Tag Wikis?" to use actual list items, like as in the "How to Format/Tag/Edit" blurbs.

Comment: This was pointed out in a comment on the answer by the responding staff member to the question you linked, but they [declined to fix it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370013/how-to-format-tag-uses-creating-less-accessible-lists#comment1255148_376511), stating that it was "taking it too far".

Comment: @Sonic I read that as a joke, not a "real" [status-declined]

Comment: Not only is it bad for accessibility, whenever I see these arrows I keep thinking they are expandable/collapsible sections.

Comment: Uh, I just logged onto a different machine and *the arrow character looks different*. It's wider. On another machine, it was less wide - pretty much an equilateral triangle (or close, at least). What I see now is closer to twice as wide as it is tall. Same browser and OS on each of the two computers. So, not only is it less accessible in general, it's apparently also inconsistent.