# The "Describe why you would make a good moderator" box uses "►", creating less-accessible "lists"

Tags: feature-request, status-review, election, accessibility, list

This is my third report of the same phenomenon ([one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370013/how-to-format-tag-uses-creating-less-accessible-lists), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383500/the-what-are-tag-wikis-editing-help-uses-creating-less-accessible-lists)) and it's the same deal. The sidebar list items look like they're a list to a visual user. However, a screen reader will be unable to interpret this block as a list, because it's marked up as if each line was a separate paragraph. Please change this to use `<li>` elements inside a `<ul>`.

```
<div class="s-sidebarwidget--content d-block">
    <p>Good moderators often:</p>
    <p><span class="dingus">►</span> have a reasonably high reputation to indicate active participation</p>
    <p><span class="dingus">►</span> show interest in their <a href="https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com">meta's community-building activities</a></p>
    <p><span class="dingus">►</span> lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members</p>
    <p><span class="dingus">►</span> exhibit those intangible traits discussed in <a href="https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/">A Theory of Moderation</a></p>
</div>
```